# Angular2 - binding to refresh page does not work in Safari while it work in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In my Angular2 app I need to load an image, do some processing on it (e.g. try to find out via OCR what is contained in the image) and show the result of what I have found on page.
The image processing (e.g. the OCR) is done by a javascript library external to my app.
The whole thing works on Chrome and Firefox (both on Mac and Windows) but does not work in Safari. Specifically the last step (i.e. the refresh of the page via binding) apparently does not get kicked in Safari.

Here is a Plnkr that reproduces the behaviour I am witnessing in my app.

https://plnkr.co/edit/BDoBkD5qo94LLeKSpyEz.

Here is the central part of the code that reproduces the behaviour I am witnessing

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {ResultContainer} from './resultContainer';

@Component({
    selector: 'top-cmp',
    providers: [],
    template: `
        <h4> Please choose an image file (e.g. a *.jpg file) using the following input element.</h4>
        <div>
            <input id="selectFile" type="file" (change)="fileSelected($event)">
        </div>
        <p>After you have chosen a file I expect to see <br>
        the following number change from 0 to 1. <br>
        This actually happens in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari</p>
        <h2>{{resultContainer.result}}</h2>
    `,
    styleUrls: [],
    inputs: [],
    directives: [],
})
export class TopComponent {
    public resultContainer = new ResultContainer();

    constructor() {
      // here I set the value that I see opening the page
        this.resultContainer.result = 0;
    }

    // this is the method called when a file is selected
    fileSelected(inEvent) {
        let imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(inEvent.target.files[0]);
        var _sourceImage: any;
        _sourceImage = new Image();
        // here I set the callback that needs to be called after
        // image processing is finished to update the page
        _sourceImage.digitsCallback = this.showResultCallback;
        _sourceImage.onload = doSomeImageProcessing;
        _sourceImage.src = imgUrl;
    }

    // this is the callback that needs to be called to update the page
    public showResultCallback= (inDigits: any[]) => {
        console.log('result --- ' + inDigits[0]);
        this.resultContainer.result = inDigits[0];
    }
}

function doSomeImageProcessing() {
    var digits = new Array<number>();
    digits.push(1);
    this.digitsCallback(digits);
}

export class ResultContainer {
    public result: number;
}
```

Thanks in advance to anybody who whish and try to help.

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7144). You need polyfiils for broken browsers.

Comment: I checked and I have all polyfills (I guess). The problem remains unfortunately.